# TokBox (OpenTok) Let users call each other using

Tags: ios, webrtc, twilio, opentok, tokbox

Using any of the OpenTok client SDKs, is it possible to call from one client to an other client, and make it look like similar to a "real" phone call?

I understand that a user X and user Y can join the same "room" if they both know the name of the room. But I don't understand how user X can send signals, to notify user Y to join a specific room, how is this done? I want it to work cross platform, i.e, work on iOS, Android devices, and web pages. My use cases are:
- app to browser
- browser to app
- app to app
- browser to browser

Is it possible in all of my use cases? Which are possible?
Is it possible to use OpenTok in a mobile app to show an incoming call even though the app is in the background (like how facebook messager and whats app works)

I've gone trough the tutorials on Tokbox website and successfully got them working, but I can't find a way to let  different users notify each other to join a session (neither in a peer-to-peer way, or via a server). How should this be done?

I cannot find that this functionality is provided by another player such a Twilio either.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Let's OpenTok do its job. In other words, use OpenTok to actually start a video session. All these things that you talked can be handled WITHOUT OpenTok, like REST APIs or Websocket or whatever.

I used to work in a similar project. Have a server to coordinate everything (all clients connected, who call who, push notifications, etc).

Whenever A needs to call B, the SERVER will start a "room" and put A and B to talk to each other...

So, don't mix the things. Let your server orchestrate everything and use OpenTok for video. It's designed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
What is the best practise to solve this? How can A and B start to communicate with each other, without having any initial information about each other?

Comment: through a server... A communicate with SERVER, B communicate with SERVER... SERVER makes both connect to each other...

Comment: How should they connect to each other? Communicating through the server only, or should they connect directly to each other? 
Im just sure what happens when two phones connect to each other (via ip address)

Comment: you need to understand how OpenTok works.... the API is very easy to understand... really simple with simple examples... I am sure you can figure out by yourself...

Comment: The thing is not that I don't understand how the OpenTok works, but how I notify user A and user B to know which room to use. Could you please help me elaborate a bit on this? I'm thinking that my server is a REST server, where the users only make requests to the server.